# What does "well" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Couldn’t Percy do that?” Harry asked. The last he had heard, the third Weasley brother was working in the Department of International Magical Cooperation at the Ministry of Magic. At these words all the Weasleys and Hermione exchanged darkly significant looks. “Whatever you do, don’t mention Percy in front of Mum and Dad,” Ron told Harry in a tense voice. “Why not?” “Because every time Percy’s name’s mentioned, Dad breaks whatever he’s holding and Mum starts crying,” Fred said. “It’s been awful,” said Ginny sadly. “**I think we’re well shut of him**,” said George with an uncharacteristically ugly look on his face.

Does it mean *better*? It is better to get rid of Percy at the moment?

Comment: In case you've not picked up on the ongoing debate below, please be aware that the answer you've accepted is (1) not substantiated by convincing **appropriate** examples of the exact usage (2) deemed incorrect by the only authority I can find who covers this usage (3) wrong in my opinion. You were very close with 'better': It's (far) better to not have him around. No intensification attaches to 'rid'; 'very rid' is not the true explanation.

Comment: Oh, are we allowed to slant people toward our answers by using comments? OP, please note that (1) the above comment is being made by a user who claims to have used _well_ the same way for over fifty years, and hence may be outdated and that (2) the answer he has posted is sourced from a text over forty years old, by an author who did not speak the language as it is spoken today (he passed away in the 90s) and (3), may be partially correct - I can consider others' views, and recognise that language my realise multiple meanings simultaneously. Please, if you feel it presents a more convincing...

Comment: argument, change your answer acceptance. It's possible for both answers to be correct in this case, but if the little tick is valuable to others, I'll happily concede it. Note that @EdwinAshworth considers a forty year old article to be a more __appropriate__ source than a dictionary, and current usage. Perhaps in the 70s, it was the right interpretation, but now? Language has changed, and quite a bit.

Comment: Thank to both of you for the new inputs(quite some heated debate), and I have done some check up on the phrase with google and found both answers makes sense under different context and authors' intents. And in this case of Rowling's writing, Edwin's certainly makes more sense: Harry asked why they didn't mention Percy, Weasleys thought they better get rid of him for a bit to let things cool off. As this is a question concerning context, it's more fair to pick the answer that fits the context for future readers.

Comment: But I am not a native speaker, so I have to go with my guts when there are two equally sound answers. But of course it's still open for discussion if there's still a even more logical explanations for the phrase here.

Comment: Yup. You should note that "they [had] better get rid of him" isn't the meaning that the answer you've selected supplies. It means something more like "we are rid of him in a good way". But it's good to know that proof by intimidation works.

Comment: @jimsug Doesn't it mean —It is paraphrased by 'It is well that he is rid of them' (archaic) or 'It's a good thing that he's rid of them'.— as in the answerer own words? Oh man, I am confused as heck now...

Comment: Yeah, the answer says "it's a good thing that he's rid of them", but this isn't equivalent to "they'd better get rid of him", which is more like "they should get rid of him".

Comment: Okay I found that the UK version(original) of the book changes the phrase to "well shot of" which seems quite idiomatic and basically means ,according to the video, it's better off/ better position to get rid of something. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9fGsesTWZQ

Comment: Yeah, I rephrased that wrong. I meant to say _it is better that they are rid of him_ So i think it settles now. Thanks

Comment: @user49119 Although I'm a native speaker, I speak American English, and this question concerns British English, so I've had an equally hard time figuring out the correct answer. After a bit of research and pondering, I think Edwin Ashworth is on the right track, although I'm reluctant to upvote his entire answer in its current state. By the way, it seems that *well shot of* is a dialectal variation on *well shut of*, and that both are used with the same meaning. (I have the UK editions of all 7 books on paper―if you include a page number in your question I can look it up to see which it says.)

Comment: @snailplane I too am an American speaker, but I have encountered this idiom from time, always in Edwin Ashworth's sense. And there is a very similar American idiom, *well out of*, in which *well* bears a different sense depending on context: referring to a physical situation it has jimsug's sense ("well out of town" = "at a considerable distance from town"), but referring to an unpleasant situation it has Edwin Ashworth's sense ("We're well out of *that* brouhaha. Let's go before they notice we're gone.")

Comment: @snailplane I think it's on page 68 according to [google books](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=sFs9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22I+think+we’re+well+shot+of+him%22&source=bl&ots=rYSeYqWP0p&sig=m3DuZzNz8dbOgOz4pii7XE6uCdM&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=ReH2U5C2MsP48QXTuYHACA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20think%20we’re%20well%20shot%20of%20him%22&f=false)

Comment: Ah, yes, my UK copy is the same!  It says *shot*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This usage of 'well' is **not** the intensifier usage, as Dwight Bolinger argues in ['Degree Words'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kZMiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22well+shut+of%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=RiUNymDRsz&sig=1557SazWvBZOUBwkJcjz-UG5RyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lXHwU96hLoaI7AbrkIHoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22well%20shut%20of%22%20meaning&f=false):

> In dealing with degree words and the comparative indeterminacy of
>   'approval' and 'fulfilment' [though 'well-spoken' obviously carries the approval sense 
>   and 'well-read' obviously carries the intensifier sense , what does eg
>   'She baked the bread well' mean?], it is well to remember that [words
>   which cannot be intensified can accept only the 'approval' sense]
>   [eg:]
>
> It was a well-conceived plan.
>
> The case was well argued. [both mean 'in a good way' not 'thoroughly']
>
> This is equally true when ['well' is used with] forms other than
>   verbs, though these are less numerous; semantically, they are very
>   much like verbs:
>
> We are well rid of them....
>
> For 'well rid of', some speakers would use 'well shut of' with 'shut'
>   used as a verbal ['well shut of' best regarded as colloquial (but
>   quite common) in the UK].

*He is well rid of them* uses 'well' as an evaluative pragmatic marker (a comment by the narrator on the value of the fact that 'he is rid of them'). Traditionally, this is a one-word reduction of a comment clause, or a[n evaluative] sentence adverbial. It is paraphrased by 'It is well that he is rid of them' (archaic) or 'It's a good thing that he's rid of them'. The usage is not the intensifier usage of well seen in say 'He is well clear of them'.

The usage is unusual in that evaluative etc pragmatic markers are usually set off by commas to distinguish such usage from the adverbial one:

> He is happily married.  [adv]
>
> He is, happily, married.   [pm]  (cf Happily, he is married.)
>
> He is, happily, well shut of them.   [pm]
>
> **but** He is well shut of them.   [pm]

shows that 'well' bucks the trend.

Comment: So in this case, the speaker being the character of Ginny Weasley, you would argue that it is the author portraying the character's evaluation of the fact that they are "shut of him"? I fail to see why it can't both intensify and evaluate "[being] shut of him".

Comment: Can you find an authority saying that that the 'well' used in 'well rid/shut of' _is_ the intensifier usage? I don't usually do this, but I'll mention that I've been familiar with the evaluative sense (and only that) for over 50 years. And Dwight Bolinger was an American linguist and Professor of Romance Languages and Literatures at Harvard – and his argument is that _This (words which cannot be intensified can accept only the 'approval' sense) is equally true when 'well' is used with forms other than verbs, and that 'well shut / rid of' is one of these cases_. Try asking on ELU. Ask JKR.

Comment: Well, in my cited definition above, based on the Collins dictionary (built using extensive corpora of the English language - and in this case, British English) states that _well_ can be used as an intensifier, and as competent users of English that we are, we may extrapolate this to various contexts. I didn't realise that we are now required to cite each phrase verbatim, I'll note that for future answers. Additionally, an appeal to authority is a logical fallacy - language is defined by its users, not by stone tablets that fell from the heavens into Dwight Bolinger's arms.

Comment: So _shut_ isn't a verb?

Comment: (1) When Jack and Jill went up the hill, 'well' wasn't used as an intensifier. Not every sense applies in every situation. Though admittedly, this isn't even the same word. (2) Why should I believe that your level of competency is greater than a Professor of Languages? (3) Faced with the weight of the counter-arguments, I'd retract my answer as misleading if I were you.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that (1) _well_ doesn't appear in that particular nursery rhyme, as well as the fact that (2) _ad hominem_ arguments are also a logical fallacy (you're on fire!), I'm not saying I'm more competent. In fact, you'll note that above, I specifically included the possibility that both meanings may apply. (3), I'm going to have to say that we should agree to disagree - I don't think the meanings are mutually exclusive, and there's no reason to favour one over the other. You don't need to source language use, as it's conventionally defined.

Comment: According to your beloved Collins, 'shut' here is a noun: n
11. get shut of / get shot of: to get rid of. However, it classes 'get rid of' as a multi-word verb, (very wisely) not labelling 'rid' separately, and RHK Webster's goes no further than 'idiom'.

Comment: I do not 'agree to disagree'. Unless you can find a single linguistics authority higher than yourself that endorses the intensifier usage of 'well' in 'well shut/rid of', you should not claim it as being a realistic possibility, and your statement "In the above usage, well shut of him means to be 'very rid of him' " is arrogant nonsense. It does not help OP at all. Even the use of 'think' in 'I think we're well shut of him' makes an intensifying usage nonsensical.

Comment: For someone who claims to have been alive for over 50 years, you sure are acting childishly. I'll just note that this was written 42 years ago, before my mother was alive and when you were just a fresh-faced child - you might wish to consider the possibility, however faint, that language evolves over time, and what was considered an apt grammatical analysis in the 70s may no longer be relevant now, and that, if you so wish, you should seek a more contemporary text that deals with today's language, rather than blindly heeding the words of a dead man.

Comment: Can you suggest one? Dictionaries usually cover ranges of senses, not 'when to use/deduce a particular sense'. I've suggested one. The fact that it almost certainly proves you wrong but you can't accept that seems more the indicator of childishness here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a British-ism - in British English, *well* can be used as an intensifier.

In much the same way as you might say that someone is well *informed*, you can use *well* in British vernacular as a generic intensifier.

[See Collins, sense 11](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well):

> (informal) (intensifier)   ⇒ "well safe"

[and Collins 'shut of'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-shut-of):

> (slang) to get rid of

In the above usage, *well shut of him* means to be "*very* rid of him".

Comment: Does he mean they are **already** "very rid of him" or **going to** "very rid of him"?

Comment: @user49119 The clause is: We **are** (well) shut of him. This is a _stative passive._ It uses _to be + past participle_ (used as an adjective). As such, it refers to **a an existing state**. It is similar to _I am married,_ which means _I am currently married._ So: we are **already** well shut of him.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I understand "***Well shot of...***" to mean: To get rid of somebody / something so that you no longer have the problems they cause.

As a native UK english speaker I've never heard “... well shut of ...”, even thought it is given in the Collins dictionary.  I think "shut" may be a more American english use.   “*Well shot of*..” is far more commonly heard in the UK.

I can't find any evidence but I do wonder if it is a 18th century British Naval slang term, like "long shot", meaning to aim at something a long way away, with little chance of hitting it.